# Deploy RDWeb on a non-default website

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2012, password-management, rdweb

I have a public website and a private site set up like below:

Public site: samplesite.com (http)
Private site: my.samplesite.com (https)

I'm trying to use RDWeb to enable users to change Active Directory passwords by following this page:
http://microsoftplatform.blogspot.com/2012/11/password-change-option-also-available.html

It works beautifully on samplesite.com/RDWeb

The question is:
    How do I enable RDWeb for my private site?  For example, I want users to be able to access RD Web thru:
    **my.samplesite.com/RDWeb**

This is mainly because I have a SSL certificate for my.samplesite.com.  I've searched online for hours and can't find a workable solution.  I've tried copying C:\Windows\Web\RDWeb to a new directory and use that as a new application, but whenever I point to my.samplesite.com/RDWeb, IIS just throws an error saying "**500 Internal server error**"